JavaScript in HTML vs seperate File
I am currently learning JavaScript and I'm trying to seperate my Code from HTML to a JavaScript-file.
WORKING CODE:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> DOM </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button>hello</button>
        <script>
            console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
        </script>
    </body>
</html> 

NOT WORKING CODE:
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> DOM </title>
        <script src="basics.js" defer></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button>hello</button>
    </body>
</html>

JavaScript:
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);

From my not working Code I get a lot of unnessecary output in the console.
        <button>hello</button>
        <script src="basics.js" defer=""></script>
    <!-- Code injected by live-server -->
<script>
    // <![CDATA[  <-- For SVG support
    if ('WebSocket' in window) {
        (function () {
            function refreshCSS() {
                var sheets = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("link"));
.
.
.
<script>

How do I get rid of it?
Thanks in advance.

Your "not working" code appears to be working just fine. Because it is deferred it's including additional markup added by the Live Server extension because it waits for the page to load completely.

What happened when it doesn't work? Is there any error? "Not working" is not enough information.

Side note: The attribute defer is a Boolean attribute. It has no equal sign that follows the attribute. The attribute is true by its sole existence.
